# Concat and minify JS files in JetBrains WebStorm IDE 10

Tags: javascript, concatenation, minify, webstorm

I'm currently using WebStorm 10.0.4 and started to think about joining and minifying some files to improve loading time on mobile devices. I was wondering how I could set up a file watcher that would concat and minfify my JS files. I have looked into grunt and other similar projects but I can't figure out how to use something like this in an automatic running file watcher.

Thanks for any suggestions :)

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/minifying-javascript.html#d139950e323

Comment: @Ananth: Well, minification is not the problem (I already do that with my CSS) but concatenation of multiple JS files is...